# Asp.net Custom Control with custom property

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I am trying to create custom RadioButtonGroup control and add custom ListItemCollection property to this control, i already added this property but my problem that:
I drag the control to my web page then open the inspector for this control and store items in my custom list(3 items), when i run my page and access this list i found its count=0 i don't know why??

This is my code:

```
  public class BaccahRadioGroup : RadioButtonList, INamingContainer
     {
        private ListItemCollection englishList; /// this is my custom list

    [Bindable(true)]
    [Localizable(true)]
    [Category(category)]
    public virtual ListItemCollection EnglishList {
        get
        {
            if (englishList == null)
            {
                englishList = new ListItemCollection();


                ((IStateManager)englishList).TrackViewState();

             }

            return englishList;
         }

       protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
          base.Render(writer);
         }

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not persisting your englishList, you're just telling the StateManager to look for changes. Persist it into the ViewState. If it is null, look into the ViewState. If there isn't one either, create a new one, and store that one into the ViewState.

Comment: Please Mr Alexander show me with code how can i persist my englishList because i don't understand you

Comment: [Developing Custom ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx) and 
[How to: Create an ASP.NET User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - 

These will help you.

Comment: Please,Mr Alexander if you can give me simple code for this problem i will be very thanked because i tried everything to solve this problem but up till now i did not solve the problem.......thanks for your help